# how to make google sheet updated automatically using importxml

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

i have the following elements on in some url

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select id="geniee_adserverbundle_zone_masterIabCategory" name="geniee_adserverbundle_zone[masterIabCategory]" class="form-control master-category-tier1"><option value="1" selected="selected">Arts &amp; Entertainment</option><option value="2">Automotive</option><option value="3">Business</option><option value="4">Careers</option><option value="5">Education</option><option value="6">Family &amp; Parenting</option><option value="7">Health &amp; Fitness</option><option value="8">Food &amp; Drink</option><option value="9">Hobbies &amp; Interests</option><option value="10">Home &amp; Garden</option><option value="11">Law, Gov't &amp; Politics</option><option value="12">News</option><option value="13">Personal Finance</option><option value="14">Society</option><option value="15">Science</option><option value="16">Pets</option><option value="17">Sports</option><option value="18">Style &amp; Fashion</option><option value="19">Technology &amp; Computing</option><option value="20">Travel</option><option value="21">Real Estate</option><option value="22">Shopping</option><option value="23">Religion &amp; Spirituality</option><option value="24">Uncategorized</option><option value="25">Adult Content</option><option value="26">Illegal Content</option></select>

</div>
```

i want to get the selected option from the mentioned combobox above. which is `Arts &amp; Entertainment`

i tried the following formula, and it's not working

```
=IMPORTxml(L72,"//select[@id='geniee_adserverbundle_zone_masterIabCategory']//option[@selected='selected']")
```

please note that `L72` is a cell where my friends input the specified url.

what i want to do is, when my friends update the URL, google sheet update its cell automatically.

is there anything wrong with my formula or the page prohibit me from scraping their data ?

update : the page is not public, you have to logged in first to get the access. but my account is currently logged in,and when i open the URL, browser redirect me to specified page which contains the mentioned elements.

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTXML only works on public pages. One alternative is to use the [URL Fetch service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/).